# cassandraUnit TestExecutionListener Error?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra-unit and I've been stuck trying to get a simple test going with Spring testing.

I am trying to get Cassandra-Unit working but I can't get a test running and I'm getting the following error message:

```
2014-09-19 11:08:22,438 [main] WARN  test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener@6221a451] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void controllerTests.cassandraTest.test()] for test instance [controllerTests.cassandraTest@52719fb6]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
at org.cassandraunit.spring.AbstractCassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.dataSetLocations(AbstractCassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.java:88)
at org.cassandraunit.spring.AbstractCassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.startServer(AbstractCassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.java:57)
at org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.java:18)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:348)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:57)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
... 25 more
    2014-09-19 11:08:22,444 [main] DEBUG cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper - Cleaning cassandra keyspaces on localhost:9171
    2014-09-19 11:08:23,223 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG socket.nio.SelectorUtil - Using select timeout of 500
    2014-09-19 11:08:23,223 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG socket.nio.SelectorUtil - Epoll-bug workaround enabled = false
```

On the JUnit Failure Trace, I get a similar error.

Here are my dependencies (basically the same as the cassandra-unit examples)

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here's my basic test class:

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @TestExecutionListeners({ CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
   @CassandraDataSet()
   @EmbeddedCassandra
   public class cassandraTest {

       @Test
       public void test() {
           fail("Not yet implemented");
       }

   }
```